# USE SSIS to update Oracle table column with Null after the value has been assigned in SQL Server to a similar column

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis

I have a data table in Oracle that has the following columns:

```
Record_ID, Run_ID, PO_Type, PO_NUM, DateTime
```

When a PO is created, all the columns are populated except for `Run_ID`:

```
Record_ID, Run_ID, PO_Type, PO_Num, DateTime
---------------------------------------------------
1374,            , NEW_PO , 12345 , 20211117123456
1375,            , NEW_PO , 12346 , 20211117123545
```

These records are currently exported out of our system via SSIS where they get imported into a SQL Server database. This is where they will be assigned a `RUN_ID` which will be unique to all of the data runs that were exported (everything that was exported at one time will have the same `Run_ID`):

```
RECORDID, SYSTEM, RUN_ID, PO_TYPE, PO_NUM, DATETIME
---------------------------------------------------------
1374,     ORDER , 5078  , NEW_PO , 12345 , 20211117123456
1375,     ORDER , 5078  , NEW_PO , 12346 , 20211117123545
```

I then need to write back to the Oracle database this `Run_ID` and update the `PO_TYPE` from `NEW_PO` to `Processed_PO` so my Oracle database would then look like this:

```
Record_ID, Run_ID, PO_Type      , PO_Num, DateTime
--------------------------------------------------------
1374,     5078   , Processed_PO , 12345 , 20211117123456
1375,     5078   , Processed_PO , 12346 , 20211117123545
```

The problem I am having is, this all needs to happen within the same SSIS pull, as it is the only tool I have available to me, and I don't know how to begin to tackle this, so any advice on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The right solution may well depend on exactly _how_ the RUN_ID is generated and assigned to the rows on the MSSQL side.  You may also have timing issues to consider, so how you are selecting the rows on the Oracle end to be exported is also relevant.

Comment: I have distinct data flow tasks that are 1) Pulling the data from the Oracle DB 2) Assigning the Distinct Run_ID to the MS_SQL data and I want to have a 3rd Dataflow task do the update to Oracle so that there is no chance of the Run_ID not beging generated as of yet.  The RUN_ID is generated from a SQL Table.  In Dataflow Task 2 the SQL is Update SQL_PO Set Run_ID = RUN_ID_TRACKER.RUN_ID 
Then another SQL Task does
Update RUN_ID_TRACKER
SET RUN_ID = RUN_ID + 1

Comment: Couldn't you simply add a task that runs the update statement on the Oracle table using the RUN_ID you wanted?  Store the run_id in a user variable within the package and use it for the Oracle update.

Comment: @MplsDBA, I am trying to get the way to do something along those lines, yes.  But I also want to make sure that I am updating only the Record_ID's that I pulled ( it is possible that other PO's may have been added into the system while this was being pulled and I do not want to run the risk of updating one of them with a Run_ID when they have not actually been processed. ) So I do feel that a way to validate that the Record_ID's that have been processed are the one's that are getting the correct Run_ID's is a good method, so some method of check and balance should be included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your helpful additional information, I understand now that your concern is mostly surrounding making sure that only the rows you extract are the ones you update later with the RUN_ID.

The simplest way I could see doing this is to use the PO_TYPE column and introduce a new status of something like 'PO_Processing'.  I don't know your environment / data model so this may or may not be feasible to do - maybe you have limitations to what you can enter here - but the SSIS package steps would then look something like this:

1. Update the Oracle rows you want

`update oracle_table set po_type = 'In_Transit_PO' where <your criteria>`

2. Perform your extract using this status as the selection criteria
3. Load the data into SQL Server
4. Store the new RUN_ID in a user variable in the package
5. Use the user variable to update the SQL Server rows

`update SQL_PO set Run_ID = (?) where <your criteria> ('?' maps to your defined package variable)`

6. Update RUN_ID_TRACKER to increment the next RUN_ID
7. Use the user variable to update the Oracle rows by mapping it (exact syntax may be slightly different depending on which provider your package is configured to use)

`update oracle_table set PO_Type = 'Processed_PO', RUN_ID='?' where PO_Type = 'In_Transit_PO'`

Done this way, you allow new POs to be generated on the Oracle side while the load is running, but you ensure that only the rows you extracted are the ones you update with the RUN_ID.  A couple extra steps in the package but they are each very simple.  Not only that, in the event of errors in the process, you have a record of exactly which subset of records it's trying to process, making debugging easier.

Come to think of it you could reduce the steps a bit by obtaining the run_id value and putting it in the variable *before* your load step, then you already have the value to include when you insert the rows - no need to to a secondary update on the SQL_PO table.